# How to change import path of svg sprite

Tags: gulp, svg-sprite

svg-sprite to generate icons in my project. But I have one problem with configuration. I want to change import path in scss file as I use separate task to compile scss. I ve set the the svg-sprite config something like this:

```
mode: {
      view: { // Activate the «view» mode
              bust: true,
                dimensions: true,
                sprite: '../../../icons.svg',
                render: {
                    scss : {
                        dest : '_icons.scss',
                    }
                }...
```

and when it builds and compile scss it try to import from

```
background: url("../../../icons-2ccc073d.svg") no-repeat;
```

but what I want is url to be '../imgs/icons-2ccc073d.svg
Any help?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change sprite to '../imgs/